# Ruby float to Binary32

Tags: ruby, floating-point, binary

I've been looking all over to find if there is a method that converts a float number(ex: `123.456`) into a binary32.  I've found a lot of solutions that go from binary32 to float, but not vice versa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert binary32 to float in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698101/how-to-convert-binary32-to-float-in-ruby)

Comment: I saw that post, but no clue how it works.  I feel like its because everything in ruby is an object, I need to somehow obtain real floating number.

Comment: `pack` and `unpack` are useful for converting between binary formats. It doesn't matter that everything's an object, even floating point numbers. To reverse the process of an `unpack` you usually just call `pack` with the same specification.

Comment: Did you try `[123.456].pack('e')`? Exactly what format of output are you looking for?

Comment: I want to convert 123.456 to 01000010111101101110100101111001.  [123.456].pack('e') gave me a funky return "y\xE9\xF6B"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above is awesome but I have a few simplifications:

```
[123.456].pack('g').bytes.map{|n| "%08b" % n}.join
```

Using the `'g'` flag instead of `'e'` avoids having to `reverse` the output from `pack`.
The `bytes` method does the same thing as calling `.ord` on each character does.
Then instead of taking the 4 integers and doing the sum/bit shift you map each to an 8 character binary string and join them together.

Comment: The `g` option is a great catch and does get rid of the `reverse`. However, the solution you're showing doesn't have, as an intermediate value, the entire binary value I thought @TakaGoto desired (versus just the ASCII binary string). that's what the `inject` does in the solution I proposed. So the solution that outputs binary would be `[123.456].pack('g').each_char.inject(0) { |sum,c| sum = (sum << 8) + c.ord }`.

Answer (score 8):

The "funky" `y\xE9\xF6B` value is the actual binary value represented as a string.

If you want to convert that to a string representation of the binary value:

```
"%032b" % [123.456].pack('e').reverse.each_char.inject(0) { |sum,c| sum = (sum << 8) + c.ord }
=> "01000010111101101110100101111001"
```

So breaking it down, this gives you the "funky" binary value packed into a string:

```
[123.456].pack('e')
```

The rest converts the "binary string" into a an integer (the appropriate binary digits of the float "casted" to integer):

```
reverse               # Handles the endian-ness
each_char             # Grabs each character in the reversed string
inject                # Concatenates the chars converted directly to binary
```

And then the `"%032b" %` displays it as a binary string so you can look at it.

EDIT: As @looby astutely observed, 'g' can be used in `pack` instead of 'e' to avoid the `reverse` step, shortening this solution to: `[123.456].pack('g').each_char.inject(0) { |sum,c| sum = (sum << 8) + c.ord }` (and use `"%032b" %...` as before in order to display it).

Answer (score 3):

You should use [String#unpack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-unpack) and [Array#pack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-pack) :

```
[123.456].pack('g').unpack('B*').first
#=> "01000010111101101110100101111001"
```